# Is the philosophy of LaTeX actually realized in practice?

Tags: latex-misc

The LaTeX project website explains that authors should concern themselves more with their content and not worry about typesetting design--which is what good designers are meant to do.  The same philosophy is stated in various intros and answers to "why LaTeX?".  On the other hand, many tout LaTeX's superior typesetting and nice-looking output.  But without being a designer, am I supposed to forever generate the same vanilla style provided by default document classes with popular LaTeX installations?

Before answering, please consider:  Is it really possible to still primarily concern myself with content rather than having to become a LaTeX aficionado just to add a bit of uniqueness to my document style?  I perceive a culture of eventually having to learn much LaTeX minutia, needing to tweak and combine classes, creating and managing custom packages, etc.  Sample package documentation looks like a nightmare if all I want is to choose a different presentation of my existing content.  Are there any long-time users who really feel like the LaTeX vision is realized?  Have you really ever generated a document for publication (e.g. print), then easily and quickly reformatted in another style (e.g. web or another journal), all *without* having to search, install and manage multiple packages, or writing your own custom-designed classes or packages, having a massive preamble and markup galore just for a few special tweaks, having to read new documentation and debug changes for a week, etc.?

Comment: I’m afraid this is a typical opinion-based question and, as such, not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Short answer: yes. I've done this on multiple occasions with my own documents. Right now it takes a careful document(-class) design, but LaTeX3 concepts will make this easier for class-writers. (edit: "if all I want is to choose a different presentation of my existing content" especially hits home. This is easy with a keyval-based markup approach.)

Comment: Yes. Even when I use my own classes and packages, I don't work on the class at the same time as the content. The exception to this is if I'm creating a diagram or something like that, where form and content merge. But not for text. Even if it is tweaking a preamble, I try to keep that distinct from editing content. And largely succeed, I think. Especially if the content requires enough attention to be absorbing.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti  I considered as much, but an answer to my last question can be objective.  If anyone can answer "yes" with a bit of explanation, it must not all be opinion.  Also, I have no idea where else to ask such a thing and  I suppose the users on Stack Exchange are the best to answer this.  It is better than a simple "Why should I use LaTeX?" which has been asked and answered many times with various opinions.  My question actually gets to the heart of what LaTeX is supposedly about, so please don't just mark this as a bad question because it might generate a few opinions.

Comment: As a whole, the question asks for opinions. The very last part might be answered objectively, but that is only one question among others here (violating the one-question-per-question idea) and is itself too broad. This part of the question, in particular, also seems designed to inflame and is something of a rant. I understand that you may find LaTeX frustrating, but venting that frustration does not make for an answerable, on-topic question. And marking it off-topic does not make it bad. It just marks it off-topic for this site. Good questions can be unsuitable for the Q&A format itself.

Comment: @CadePerkins: Your question is reasonable and you may have plenty of good reasons to ask it, but this is not the point.  The point is that your question is by far too broad to admit a precise, technical answer.  It would be a different thing if, for example, you were asking about how to organize a *specific* content in such a way of being able to typeset it in a certain number of different styles just by changing one or two declarations; and if your question were accompanied by a MWE that showed what you have tried so far.

Comment: Got it.  I agree Stack Exchange is a great resource because of the ideals you've pointed out.  Sometimes these type of questions bug me too, but sometimes nobody complains and it leads to great discussion and answer.  I also wasn't trying to vent as much as briefly present what I've found in only a week of looking into LaTeX.  I haven't used it myself to have my own frustration, only realized that the evidence seemed to contradict the touted ideal.

Comment: Well, people don't tend to post questions when they're busy writing content. At least, they don't tend to post questions *here*. So surely you must appreciate a certain selection bias in your sampling strategy? If you are writing a paper, say, and don't know where it will end up, the key thing is to stick to a standard class (`article`) and ***stick with the default format***. Don't load any packages you can possibly do without. Don't change the format or font more than you absolutely must. Then it will be easier by far to adapt to whichever specific format you need later.

Comment: This is the typical question worth asking on good old usenet group comp.text.tex

Comment: i'll swim against the tide to mention one point that has annoyed me for a long time.  many publishers provide their own document classes, and many of them do not base the main structure of those classes on the basic classes `article`, `book` and `proc`.  while the top matter of those classes is seriously underspecified (publishers often provide that information to indexers and aggregators, where clear identification of each element is required), the main elements structuring the body are common, and keeping the same names can help an author switch classes easily.

Comment: TLDR: No. To answer your question, rather than give you a bunch of obstacles and non-answers: You're intuition is pretty spot on. If you take pride in your work, you *will* spend *significantly* more time fiddling, styling, formatting, drawing & arranging tables & figures & headers & margins, etc. than you will researching and writing your thesis. It *will* be frustrating. If you have the will and persistence (or perhaps creativity or some exception to the rule), you will get to a point where the LaTeX philosophy is realized in practice. Still, I recommend & encourage it. Also, it looks great.